# How to convert byte[] c# to java byte[]

Tags: java, c#, arrays, range, byte

I have this code in C#

`byte[] t = {6, 250, 215}`.

But in Java is

`byte[] t = {6, -6, -41}`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: c# `byte` and java `byte` are not equivalent. Java's `byte`s are signed.

Comment: So if I use md5 encryption in C # I will never be able to convert in java?

Comment: Both arrays are `{ 0b00000110, 0b11111010, 0b1101011 }`. They have different interpretations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *How to solve this problem*

the 1st is read about [how java represents data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)..:

> **byte**: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
> It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).
> The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays,
> where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in
> place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact
> that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of
> documentation.

as [@bradimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5884788/bradimus) statements, java's byte is an 8-bits 2 complement signed int
but in C# you will never see a negative byte value

## Hint:

if you consider to make a conversion...

> -6 **in java can be** 256+(-6) = 250 **in C#**

and carefully consider the max and min in a java-byte if you need to convert from C# to java....